# JavaScript self-invoking function

Tags: javascript, iife

I got this example from page 79 of a book called Object Oriented JavaScript by Stoyan Stefanov.  Not really knowing what to do, the first time I ran this program (by hitting enter) it returned 'undefined'. After that, following the author's instructions, I called it `a();` and got the alert 'Worky worky'

My questions are

a) Did I do the first step correctly? i.e. am I supposed to run a self-invoking program by merely hitting "enter/return"?

b) if I was correct to just hit "enter/return" to run the program, why did it give a result of "undefined."  This program, says the author, refuns a reference (on its first run-through) to the function actualWork() ? if it returns a reference, why is that considered undefined? Is it important somehow?

Note that I tried to enter the code in jsfiddle.net and then hit run and nothing happened, but that I got "undefined" when I ran it the first time in the console and then the alert afterwards when I did a();

```
var a = function() {
    function someSetup(){
        var setup = 'done';
    }
    function actualWork(){
        alert('Worky-worky');
    }
    someSetup();
    return actualWork;
}();
```

Comment: The function returns another function which contains the alert. So after calling your outer function, it will resolve to `actualWork` being set to `a`. When you then call `a`, you basically call the `actualWork` function, i.e. *then* you get the alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) depending on how your interpreter works, yes, simply running the script (by pressing return) defines function a();

b) it gave "undefined" because the program itself doesn't return anything, but the function a(); does.
the code you quoted above represents a function a(); which, when invoked, should do the following:

1. define 2 other (temporary) functions
2. run one of them (someSetup)
3. return the other one.

so i would use the program by:

1. running to define a();
2. calling `var x=a();`
3. (optional) checking if `setup=='done'`
4. calling `x();` (which was returned by a()) should show the alert.

**EDIT**
sorry, i didn't see the }(); at the end, so it's not 100% correct. the (); at the end is - as Jon and Tomasz both said - short form for "take the function's return value as a new function and run it immediately".

Answer (score 4):

This code is equivalent to:

```
var f = function() {
    function someSetup(){
        var setup = 'done';
    }
    function actualWork(){
        alert('Worky-worky');
    }
    someSetup();
    return actualWork;
};

var a = f();
```

So: You are creating variable `f` and assigning a function to it. Then You assign the result of invoking `f()` to `a`, which happens to be a function as well (this is done implicitly in the original code). And at the very end you can run `a()`, which runs the the function **returned** by `f()`.

Answer (score 4):

"Self-invoking" means that this code has an immediate effect immediately after it is executed by the compiler, *even though all the code is inside a function*. This happens because the function is immediately invoked (those `()` in the last line).

This is also what would have happened if you wrote just

```
function someSetup(){
    var setup = 'done';
}
function actualWork(){
    alert('Worky-worky');
}
someSetup();
return actualWork;
```

The difference here is that the "self-invoking program" (which is a bad description for what it is, IMHO) allows you to do this without making the names `someSetup` and `actualWork` visible to the calling code -- this is generally desirable.

With that explained, let's answer your questions:

1. The code snippet does not `return` anything itself (even if it assigns to `a` something that *is* returned by a function); therefore your JS IDE reports that its return value is `undefined`.
2. The reference to function `actualWork` is returned fine (it's the value assigned to `a`); you saw that yourself when you successfully called it with `a()`.

Answer (score 1):

`undefinded` is returned from statements `var a = ...` that is OK. Reference is returned by the right side of assigment.

Answer (score 1):

The anonumous function is invoked immediately and returns a reference to the function `actualWork` within it. So `a` contains this reference and can be invoked by itself. So `a();` should give you the alert.